# Mostrar registros con ajax

Tags: php, ajax

Estoy tratando de obtener las subcategorías de mis categorías con AJAX pero al momento de hacerle un console.log solo me muestra una sola subcategoría, no estoy seguro de que estoy haciendo mal, dejo mis códigos para ver si alguien me logra mostrar mi error y ayudar, muchas gracias de antemano.

esta es mi función con la que hago mi petición AJAX

```
function obtenerSubCategorias(idCategoria){
$.ajax({
    type:"POST", 
    data:"idCategoria=" + idCategoria,
    url:"../procesos/categorias/obtenerSubCategoria.php",
    success:function(respuesta){
        respuesta = jQuery.parseJSON(respuesta);
        
        console.log(respuesta);
    }
})
```

}

Aca mando mi dato con el método POST:

```
<?php
 require_once "../../clases/Categorias.php";
 $Categorias = new Categorias();

 echo json_encode($Categorias->obtenerSubCategoria($_POST['idCategoria']));
?>
```

Esta es mi clase categorías

```
public function obtenerSubCategoria($idCategoria){
        $conexion = Conectar::conexion();

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM categoria WHERE id_padre = '$idCategoria'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);

        $categoria = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

        $datos = array(
                       "idCategoria" => $categoria['id_categoria'],
                       "idSubCategoria" => $categoria['id_padre'],
                       "nombreCategoria" => $categoria['nombre']
                       );
        return $datos;
    }
```

muestro mi tabla categorías que cuenta con una relaciona de id_padre con id_categoria para que el id_padre me diga a que categoría pertenece y así sucesivamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

acá muestro mi resultado del log que solo me trae un solo registro y realmente debería traerme 2 según la tabla:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te está trayendo un solo registro porque eso es lo que estás obteniendo de los resultados.

Mucha gente piensa que aplicando **una sola vez** cualquiera de los métodos `fetch_`  en los resultados de `mysqli_query` ya basta para obtener **todas la filas**. Pero no es así. `mysqli_query()` te devuelve un recurso y tienes que vaciarlo para ir sacando los datos fila por fila. Por eso, si observas los ejemplos del [Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) (ver **Ejemplo 1**) te dará cuenta de que los métodos como `fetch_assoc` se aplican dentro de un bucle (por lo general `while`).

Entendido eso, tu problema debería resolverse obteniendo cada fila dentro de un bucle:

```
public function obtenerSubCategoria($idCategoria){
        $conexion = Conectar::conexion();
        #Asignaremos el alias que necesitamos para cada clave
        $sql = "SELECT 
                 id_categoria AS idCategoria,
                 id_padre AS idSubCategoria,
                 nombre AS nombreCategoria
                FROM categoria WHERE id_padre = '$idCategoria'";
        $datos=array(); 
        if ($result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql)) {
            while ( $fila = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ) {
                #Gracias a los alias, ahora podemos hacer esto sin más
                #$datos se irá llenando con cada $fila
                $datos [] = $fila;
            }
        } else {
            $datos["error"]="Ha ocurrido en un error en la consulta";
        }
        return $datos;
    }
```

Con esto debería funcionar. Además, se ha incorporado el manejo de una situación de error. Luego en Javascript puedes controlar si la respuesta tiene una clave error para actuar en consecuencia.

Por último, te advierto de que tu código al altamente vulnerable a ataques de *Inyección SQL*. Deberías usar consultas preparadas para corregir ese gravísimo riesgo de seguridad.

Comment: muchas gracias efectivamente funciona y me muestra todos los elementos en la consola.